# Is Angular *ngFor rendering asynchronous?

Tags: angular

In the code below, the line `this.images = response.map( r => r.url).slice(0,10);` fills the `images` array and then `ngFor` renders the data in the view. After that a Jquery function is called to init an image slider but that function needs to be inside a `timeout` to make a pause while the HTML elements are rendered with `ngFor`.

I thought `ngFor` was synchronous meaning that when `images` array gets its data then `ngFor` renders the HTML and after that, the Jquery function is called. But it doesn't look like that.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

declare var $ : any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <div class="galeria">
            <div *ngFor="let img of images"><img src="{{img}}" ></div>
        </div>
              `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  images= [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loadImages();
  }

  loadImages(){
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    .subscribe((response : any[]) => {
      
          this.images = response.map( r => r.url).slice(0,10);

          setTimeout(()=> this.loadGalery(),10);
    });
  }


loadGalery(){
    $('.galeria').bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: false,
      slideWidth:900,
      speed:700,
      infiniteLoop: true,
      auto: true,
      pager: true,
    });
}
}
```

[Live example Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3nyjyg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Generally using jQuery with Angular isn't a good idea unless you have a good reason. I don't see any jQuery here but it's usually due to the fact that there's some processing done outside Angular's "knowledge"... much like needing to wrap logic in `$scope.$apply` with AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You pause 10ms to wait for angular to finish rendering, but of course it might take longer than that. On a device with weak CPU it could take even longer than on your machine so this method isn't very reliable.

You could try executing the jquery in the `ngAfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook (see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Change detection cycle has to complete before rendering is done. Set timeout is will push callback on macro task queue and will be executed after DOM has been updated.